# Setup golang environment using jetbrains

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I have setup an golang developing envionemnt using idea (13.1 community edition).
It seems the SDK is recognized.
However, I could not create a GO file by right click the "New" under the source folder. (The item of "go" is grayed)
Currently I have to manually set the file extension to ".go" and edit the file, but autocomplete is OK.
This only exist on my Mac(with version 10.9.4)
I have set the GOPATH directory access mode to 777 but still not work.
This works fine on windows7.
So what should I do ?[image]

This is what it looks like in windows
[image]

```
Thanks VonC, I already tried the /Users/Tom/go setting, this doesn't work and I switch to this root path.
here's my previous setting

 macbook:home root# go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/mac/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

And this is what is look like in the /Users/Tom/Go[image]

Thanks VonC, however, this doesn't work. I am not sure what's the reason.
This is the envionment setting using GOCODE
[image]
This is several steps!
[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAqpH.jpg)

[image: step 2]

[image: step3]

[image: step4]

[image: step5]

[image: this is envionment seting]

By the way, I noticed that there are a difference from mac and windows when creating a new Go Project 
at this step, the windows platform will show a "project sdk" while mac won't.
[image: mac and windows not exactly at this step]

Comment: Your first picture could work if GOPATH was set to /GOCODE

Comment: Your last should work if `GOPATH` was set to `/Users/Tom/go`, not `/Users/Tom/Go`: `go` and `Go` aren't exactly the same, since HFS+ (the Mac filesystem) is usually configured to be case insensitive but case preserving.

Comment: What was the exact setting you had to modify to make it work?

Comment: I tried both /GOCODE and /Users/mac/go, and it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: by the way , I am sure that the plugin is newest version.

Comment: I thought you are very sure it's caused by the GOPATH setting, so I accepted it.  Interestingly, the autocomplete feature works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60373/discussion-between-python-and-vonc).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your discussion invite. Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your IntelliJ project reference the right path within `GOPATH`.
From the [plugin page](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin):

> If you have only one directory in the GOPATH and you are creating a project inside that path when you are working with packages that are part of the project you must still specify the whole import path for them, not the relative one. Example:
>
> - `GOPATH` is: /home/florin/go
>     the correct way to setup a project called demogo is: `/home/florin/go/src/github.com/dlsniper/demogo/`
> - new package is: /home/florin/go/src/github.com/dlsniper/demogo/newpack
> - the correct import statement is: github.com/dlsniper/demogo/newpack not newpack

---

Also make sure you have the latest version of the plugin, as [issue 756](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/756) illustrates that IntelliJ IDEA 13 doesn't create the project directory structure on Mac OS X.

---

Finally, check if IDEA has correctly detected `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`:
See the page "[Fix missing environment paths (Mac)](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/blob/master/Missing%20ENV.md#--mac-os-x)".

---

The [OP python](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1804926/python) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601023/setup-golang-environment-using-jetbrains/25601081#comment39993549_25601081):

> - If I have create a new Go project, this new feature is disabled.
> - **If I create a new Java Command line App, then I could right click and add new Go file**.

Comment: GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: GOPATH=""? GOPATH should be set to your workspace (https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces). Check also https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/blob/master/Missing%20ENV.md#--mac-os-x

Comment: Hi Vonc, I think I found the solution although not sure about the rule cause. If I have create a new Go project, this new feature is disabled. If I create a new Java Command line App, then I could right click and add new Go file. -_-  However, this finally work for me . thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on either the top-level project or on the *src* directory and then go to *Mark Directory As > Sources Root*. After this you will be able to access the enabled *Go* context menus.